# ColdFusion.Window.create callbackhandler issue

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, callback, handler

I'm trying to use the callbackhandler entry for the configuration parameter for ColdFusion.Window.create().  I have the following js functions below.  Within populateWindow2() I have calls to other functions that I intend to only run after the window is rendered as these functions need to make references to elements within the created window.

Triggering populateCFwindow with:

```
<input id="selectProcessorButton" onclick="javascript:populateCFwindow();">

populateCFwindow = function(){
      ColdFusion.Window.create(...{callbackhandler:populateWindow2()}).

}

populateWindow2 = function(){
  initSearchgetProcessorList();
  initTable_selectProcessor();
}
```

The issue I am having is that the init functions above still fire before the window is completely rendered.

I appreciate any feedback.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the parentheses which are invoking the function and passing it's result to `callbackHandler` (`undefined`) instead of passing a reference to the populateWindow2 function .

```
<input id="selectProcessorButton" onclick="javascript:populateCFwindow();">

populateCFwindow = function(){
      ColdFusion.Window.create(...{callbackhandler:populateWindow2}).

}

populateWindow2 = function(){
  initSearchgetProcessorList();
  initTable_selectProcessor();
}
```

Comment: removing the parens in the callbackhandler: configuration is not firing populateWindow2().  I used the following to test if this function is being triggered.

populateWindow2 = function(){alert("hello"); initSearchgetProcessorList(); initTable_selectProcessor(); }

Comment: I don't understand your point, you don't want to invoke the function at the point of assignment.

Comment: How do you invoke once the window has finished rendering?

Comment: The callbackhandler function, which is a reference to populateWindow2, will be run once the window is created

Comment: Is this a function that I need to specifically invoke either within populateCFwindow or populateWindow2?  Or is this the natural behavior of using callbackhandler within ColdFusion.Window.create()?

Comment: No, you are telling `ColdFusion.Window.create` to run `populateWindow2` to run once the window is created by setting the callback handler as a reference to that function

Comment: That is the issue that I am having.  populateWindow2 is not firing.  I placed an alert within this function to test, but returns nothing.

Comment: Then I can only imagine you have a problem within the `populateCFWindow` function somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and checked their JavaScript code. The configuration property name is `callbackHandler`, not `callbackhandler`. Adobe needs to update their docs, this problem drove me nuts!!!